# What makes a song a Christmas song?

Tags: harmony, history

Apart from lyrics, what features have been common to Christmas music in different traditions and eras of classical, folk and modern music?

Have there been specific melodic intervals, structure, harmony, rhythm, tempo, instruments, etc. that are uniquely or strongly associated with Christmas music in different eras and settings?  Are any of them universal or nearly so?

Comment: You must have listened to hundreds - what similarities do a lot of them contain - rhythm and tempo don't seem to be common factors.

Comment: Welcome! I'm afraid, under the parameters, this is going to be a very opinionated topic, and those [aren't covered here](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Lyrics, of course, make it a Christmas song; beyond that, "Christmas music" isn't actually a genre. Many favorites share musical elements simply because they were written in the same time period. But this is akin to arguments over whether *Die Hard* is a "Christmas movie," with some arguing that referencing Christmas is enough and others that a "Christmas movie" must have a certain tone.

Comment: I think lyrics are the only *musical* element that qualifies a tune as being "a Christmas song." We won't find many musical similarities between Sia's "Everyday is Christmas," "Frosty the Snowman," "Away in a Manger," and "The Christmas Song." But in addition to musical elements, cultural associations can also qualify a song as "a Christmas song." For example, Fur Elise was not considered a Christmas song until it was featured in *A Charlie Brown Christmas*.

Comment: Why was this question closed? It seems to be asking about analysis. Just because the answer is "no" doesn't make it off-topic, does it? Justifying that answer would entail analyzing songs to illustrate the differences. If everyone agrees that the answer is no, how is it opinion-based?

Comment: @jdjazz To me it’s slightly opinion based and completely genre identification, even if it’s coming from the other side of genre identification. Imagine the question “what’s makes a a song grunge?” Perhaps that kind of thing has a home on Music Fans.SE but it doesn’t seem at all a good fit here.

Comment: @jdjazz One example of the opinion nature of this question is my conviction that Beethoven’s untitled bagatelle that was dedicated to Elise is in no way at all Christmas music, and I’ve never heard anyone assert that it is or play it in December along with other music that is widely seen as Christmas music. Not that I’m saying you’re wrong, just that what is and isn’t Christmas music is subjective.

Comment: @ToddWilcox, the question is about songs with Christmas lyrics. The first sentence is "Apart from lyrics..." which doesn't seem ambiguous to me and seems pretty clearly defined. IMO calling this question genre identification is a mischaracterization. Answers to this question have the form "no, there aren't any other common musical elements" or "yes, all Christmas music has a tempo between X and Y bpm." Those aren't topics for MusicFans.SE, as far as I know.

Comment: @ToddWilcox, you must not be a fan of A Charlie Brown Christmas. "The Peanuts character Schroeder performs this in the TV special A Charlie Brown Christmas, which many American families watch every Christmas season. As a result, the piece is often associated with Christmas and shows up on some Christmas playlists." -[source](https://www.songfacts.com/facts/ludwig-van-beethoven/fur-elise)

Comment: My point was not that cultural association is the correct way to answer the question. I suggesting that, if one were motivated to ask the question because of a sense of cohesion, pointing only to a musical explanation would overlook cultural/sentimental factors. Based on how the question is phrased, they're not asking about Fur Elise. It's just a good example of how cultural association can change a song's meaning for the listener.

Answer (score 4):

Being written by an American Jewish composer during the 'golden age' helps a lot!  (But then, that applies to all the best songs on any subject.)

Nothing, really. Throw some sleighbells into the orchestration. Or a descending run of second inversion diatonic triads.   Apart from that, if you can find any musical feature linking Silent Night, White Christmas, Frosty the Snowman, Once in Royal David's City... let us know!

(Yes, there's this.

https://www.insidehook.com/article/music/christmas-music-secret-chord-makes-sound-festive

Fun, but the argument doesn't really stand up to scrutiny. So two Christmas songs, 50 years apart, use the same (very) slightly 'outside' chord.  Big deal.)

Comment: “Being written by an American Jewish composer” classic and true! Frosty and Rudolph have the same harmony and similar melodies on their respective bridges, not much to go on though.

Comment: Yes I think we need something better than a similarity between just two Christmas songs :-)

Answer (score 4):

The most common and beloved Christmas songs are either pop songs about the holiday season from the 1950's and 60's or religious hymns. And nothing says "Christmas" quite like sleigh bells.

That's it. Christmas music is nothing more than pre-boomer era pop music with extra bells!

This isn't too surprising when you think about it. Christmas music aims to be comforting, a part of our traditions, and a way of connecting us during a holiday season focused on family and happiness. Boomers are the parents and grandparents of many of today's family's, and they grew up listening to the pop music their parents put on. So pre-boomer era pop music is nostalgic for a lot of today's heads of families, and they're passing that tradition on to everyone else. On top of that, sticking to the same songs we've been hearing for decades means that practically everyone in America and western Europe knows the Christmas canon by heart now, and that shared culture lets us all feel more connected during the holiday season. In the end, it's a good thing!

Likewise, sleigh bells are only ever heard in a modern context when making an allusion to Christmas. We don't use actual house-drawn sleighs enough for them to be a common item anywhere else, after all! So through decades of repeatition, we've burned sleigh bells as an audial shorthand for winter holidays into the collective consciousness. Again, this isn't a bad thing during a season that encourages being connected to others. We all share sleigh bells as a common cultural touch point!

There are some more recent Christmas songs that have earned a place in the Christmas canon, like Feliz Navidad and All I Want for Christmas. The same idea applies to them: They're straightforward pop songs that won the cultural lottery, got stuck in our shared imagination for long enough, and now have cemented themselves as part of our shared holiday experience. It's not that there's a type of major chord or special instrument that calls Christmas to mind (well, aside from sleigh bells). It's simply pop music that has survived the shake-out process and lodged itself in cultural memory, establishing itself as a nostalgic common ground for hundreds of millions of people to share.

Comment: Ha! "...more recent Christmas songs ... like Feliz Navidad", written *more than 50 years ago*.

Answer (score 3):

To some extent it is more a matter for cognitive science than music theory.  For example:

- The songs that existed before we were born and that our families sang or listened to in our childhood can seem as if they've existed *for all time.*
- Songs that were beloved to many members of our family when we were small can seem as if they are beloved universally.
- Songs of any kind that we only listen to or sing at a particular time of year become strongly associated with that time of year.

If you want to think only in music-theoretical terms, it depends on how wide a net you cast.  Other answers are looking somewhat more narrowly than the "classical, folk and modern" you specified, and Golden-age American holiday music definitely has some "received gestures" (sleighbells anyone?).

There won't be much in common if we look as broadly as you suggest. To wit:

**Classical** (OK fine, *Baroque*):

Christmas Concerto; Op.68 by Arcangelo Corelli:

**Folk** (you didn't say which folks; how about the last folks in Europe to be Christianized):

"Kalėdų rytu rožė inžydo" ("Christmas morning a rose bloomed") a Lithuanian folk song sung in this recording by Zosė Čiupalaitė:

**More Folk** (from some folks in a Christian tradition that most Americans don't even know exists):

"The savior of the world is born today" by Ethiopian Orthodox Tewahedo Church

**Modern** (-ish):

"Christmas Time is Here" by the Vince Guaraldi Trio:

Of course with sufficient effort, a theorist could identify some common elements between those, but they're more likely a matter of coincidence than "Christmas-ness".

...Then again, maybe there's something to those sleighbells.  "Die Schlittenfahrt" ("The Sleigh Ride") by W. A. Mozart:

"Last Snowstorm of the Year" by Low:

OK, fine it's sleighbells and 3/4 (or compound) time.